# Vim-Pandoc Overrides my Markdown Plugins

Tags: filetype-markdown, plugin-vim-pandoc

I've been trying to get the vim-pandoc plugin to play nice with markdown nvim, and have not been successful in finding help so far. The trouble seems to be that vim-pandoc sets markdown files to be recognised by vim as pandoc files which prevents the vim-markdown plugin from running syntax highlighting etc. In any case, as soon as install the vim-pandoc plugin, my syntax highlighting goes out the door in markdown. If only I could get vim-pandoc not to do this, I'd be all set. It looks like this is the way to achieve this result:

```
let g:pandoc#filetypes#pandoc_markdown = 0
```

By default, the above is set to 1, but setting it to 0 has not helped. If anyone has any ideas about how to proceed, I'd greatly appreciate the help. The issue I'm having has also been raised in the vim-pandoc GitHub [issue 70](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc/issues/70) and [issue 382](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc/issues/70), but none of the suggestions there seem to help. What I've settled for instead is using the vim-pandoc-syntax plugin as well, simply accepting that all the other markdown plugins won't work as expected. One feature I really miss is where you have a list and it auto generates the next bullet point etc., when you create a new line in the list. The vim-pandoc-syntax plugin which is supposed to pair with vim-pandoc does not have this set be default, and I'm not sure how to get it to reproduce the autogenerate list item functionality that I used to have. I've even considered adding this [bullets](https://github.com/dkarter/bullets.vim) plugin, but it feels like the better option would be to prevent vim-pandoc from getting in the way of my original markdown plugin which was working great. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Have you tried putting the `:let` *before* `:filetype on`? Re: bullets, have a look at `:help 'formatoptions'` and `:help 'formatlistpat'`

Answer (score 0):

Correct. The setting g:pandoc#modules#enabled can mess with your keybindings, and many other things. Passing an empty list helped on my case.

```
let g:pandoc#modules#enabled = []
```